# Getting exception "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have navigation controller on tab bar item 2 . I am doing some operations in tab bar item 2->navigation item 2 . when I click on button I want to go to the tab bar item 1 but at the same time I want navigation controller in 2nd tab to be set to its root view controller . I have tried following :

```
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

But when I came back from tab 1 to tab 2 . It is giving me exception :"message sent to deallocated  instance" .  What is the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: On which line it is showing that ? You are not retaining something and trying to use an object after it's deallocated

Comment: after executing `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];` , how excecution will proceed to further lines from tab at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To select first tab:**

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

**To switch tab's rootviewcontroller:**

To achieve this you have use `UITabBarBontroller's` delegate method to pop to rootviewcontroller.

write it in `AppDelegate`

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==1) {
//only for tab number 2
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)viewController ;
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
 }

}
```

P.S. don't forget to add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in AppDelegate.h